# evaluating double integral $\iint\limits_{D} \cos \left ( \frac{x-y}{x+y} \right ) dxdy$ D is a bounded closed area given by $x=0 \ y=0 \ x+y=1$

Tags: integration

evaluating double integral $$\iint\limits_{D} \cos \left (   \frac{x-y}{x+y} \right ) dxdy$$ D is a bounded closed area given by $x=0 \ y=0 \ x+y=1$

I tried substituting with variables $x-y=u \ x+y=v$ the Jacobin is $\frac{1}{2}$

$$\iint\limits_{D} \cos \left (   \frac{x-y}{x+y} \right ) dxdy \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\int _{0}^1dv\int ^{v}_{-v}\cos \dfrac{u }{v}du$$but I still have no idea to solve it.

[image]

Comment: What's the problem? You have$$\int_{-v}^v\cos\left(\frac uv\right)\,\mathrm du=\left[v\sin\left(\frac uv\right)\right]_{u=-v}^{u=v}=2v\sin(1).$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, it seemed like something went wrong when I tried it before, but it's easy to do now. Thanks~